# Cannot update Knockout UI with fresh data object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm currently having problems having the UI refresh when I'm getting new data from the server for a single item which is in an observableArray of wrapper objects which holds an object of several observables.

Consider the following:

```
var vm = {
....
localEdited: ko.mapping.fromJS(new ItemWrapper(defaultModelSerialised)), 
selected: ko.observable(null),
editItem: function(data) {
  // clone a temporary copy of data for the dialog when opening (*.localEdited on dialog)
  var clonedData = ko.toJS(data);
  ko.mapping.fromJS(clonedData, null, this.localEdited);

  // selected should now point to the item in the obserable array which will be refreshed
  this.selected(data);

  // open dialog...
},
submitDialog: function(data) {

   // submit data to server...

   // (1) commit the data back to UI (new item is return in resp.entity from server)
   vm.selected(new ItemWrapper(resp.entity));

   // at this point the UI isn't showing the updated value

   // (2) however if I do this it reflects the data change in the UI
   this.selected().Name("changed");  // updates the UI.
}
```

Can someone explain why passing in the ItemWrapper into vm.selected isn't updating the UI whereas in (2) it works. I don't want to have to set-up each property like in (2) for every property.

ItemWrapper looks like so:

```
function PoolWrapper(pool) {
    this.Name = ko.observable(pool.Name);

    // more properties...
}
```

Comment: Do you bind anything to vm.selected in html? If not, why do you expect knockout to update UI in this line vm.selected(new ItemWrapper(resp.entity)); ?

Comment: Maybe you could get something in jsFiddle to demonstrate?  Would be easier that seeing part of your code.  I am assuming that maybe you are doing `with: selected` in your UI or using a template against `selected`?

Comment: @RomanBataev: Nothing is bound to vm.selected directly. In editItem() the data passed in is from the ItemWrapper in the observableArray. The selected variable then points to the item in the array. As point (2) demonstrates it is bound to the UI ok when passing properties individually, but not when passing ItemWrapper into the selected() variable.

Comment: I've tried to create a jsfiddle but I can't get it working. Hope you get the idea though...http://jsfiddle.net/5J9aL/4/

Comment: Well, if nothing is bound to vm.selected, then nothing will happen when you change the value of vm.selected. Your jsfiddle link is not working, so I cannot go further at this point. I guess (2) works because the properties of the value of vm.selected are bound to UI somewhere.

Comment: Why does this line work then: this.selected().Name("changed");  ?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the jsfiddle link which is now working: http://jsfiddle.net/5J9aL/8/ Its making my browser unresponsive though so I think the mapping plugin is broken or I'm using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK- the issue is that your clones end up with mapping meta-data on them and eventually this causes recursion when trying calling `ko.mapping.fromJS`.

The solution is to create your clones using `ko.mapping.toJS` instead of `ko.toJS`, so that you get a clean clone (without mapping meta-data).

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/tDDBp/

Comment: Thanks for this. Not sure why ko.toJS would keep the mapping data and the ko.mapping.toJS doesn't.

Comment: ko.mapping.toJS specifically knows about the mapping options and removes them, while ko.toJS has no idea about the mapping plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Something I also stumbled upon today that I thought I'd share:

If you clone using:

```
var clone = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(itemToClone));
```

Then the clone will be stripped of any computed observables. They will exist as the last value of the function, but no longer function as a computed observable.

If your item is a complex model with computed observables that you would like to keep on your clone you can do the following:

```
var clone = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(itemToClone), null, new itemModel());
```

Where itemModel is your complex model for your item containing your computed observables.